# RDLC subreports properties not fiding the list of reports at ReportName field

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reportviewer, rdlc, subreport

I am trying to insert a subreport in a report, but at the subreport properties, the ReportName field (where I should choose the report I will use as subreport) isn't showing the list of files, even with a lot of rdlc reports at the projetc. Check the picture

[image]

What is happening?

Comment: Did you try to just type it in?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't autocomplete. If I type and run, it compiles ok but when the it shows the report, I get a message 'The subreport 'Subreport1' could not be found at the specified location OrdemPagamentoAFSubEmpenho.rdlc. 
Please verify that the subreport has been published and that the name is correct.'  in the space that I put the subreport.